# Null Pointer Exception because activity has not been created yet

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple chat that communicates with a Server running in my desktop, and I have the next activity as my Starter activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        register = findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("pascoa.ddns.net"), 59000);
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Thread(new Reader(socket, out, in, AuthActivity.this.getApplication())).start();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

This activity creates this new Thread which will run in background waiting for input from the server.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            while (true) {
                inputData = in.readObject();
                Log.d("Lmao",inputData.getClass().getName());
                if (inputData.getClass().getName().equals("com.example.mtc.Packets.Server.ClientInfo")) {
                    ClientInfo info = (ClientInfo) inputData;
                    AuthActivity.setID(info.getPrivateNumber());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                } else if (inputData.getClass().getName().equals("com.example.mtc.Packets.Server.ChatInfo")) {
                    ChatInfo info = (ChatInfo)inputData;
                    GroupChatActivity.resetMessages(info);
            }
         }
       }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But the problem is when I receive the chat info after authentication, the GroupChatActivity which is started in here, is yet to be created, so I can't update the messages which it contains.

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
      context.startActivity(intent);
```

This is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
    Process: com.example.mtc, PID: 9622
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.List.clear()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mtc.GroupChatActivity.resetMessages(GroupChatActivity.java:70)
        at com.example.mtc.Reader.run(Reader.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

code for resetting the chat which is where it is giving the error:

```
    public static void resetMessages(ChatInfo info){
        chatMessages.clear();
        for(Message e : info.getLogList()){
            chatMessages.add(e);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        input_text.setText("");
        list_messages.setSelection(list_messages.getCount() - 1);
    }
```

How would I wait for the GroupChatActivity to be started?

Comment: You can't access Activity like this `GroupChatActivity.resetMessages(info)`, rather run your operation `inputData = in.readObject();` in `GroupChatActivity`

Comment: Maybe try with an AsyncTask which in my opinon is better, than native Java thread...

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I see, but isn't a universal reader a better option?,with your solution i'd have to read the chat info in the groupChatActivity, but then the problem is that the clientInfo and chatInfo since they are sent from the server at the same time, they could get swapped and since each are required one for the authenticationActivity and another for the groupChatActivity it could bring errors couldn't it?

Comment: @dmak2709 hmm I see, I'm new in android I'll check it out too, just the whole android context, activities etc is quite confusing still xd.